# Using custom parameter with a form control as source in Data view Webpart

Tags: 2007, data-view-web-part

On a page, I have a dataview webpart to enter a new item in a list. It has just one text-box to enter data in a list field.On submit, the form is redirected to a custom page.

I want to grab the text entered by user in the text box(bound to list field) and pass it as query string parameter in next page.

I am trying to create a custom parameter with source as textbox control in the dataview.The id of the textbox looks like `ff1{pos}`.So I am not able to use it as the value of `pos` is not know at design time.

I want use this parameter in submit url. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the textbox to a variable and then use the variable in your query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to read text and pass it as query string on submit button click.

To read text from text field:

```
$("input[id^='ff1']").val()
```

Above code select value from id which start with `ff1`.